# Should I use In memory SQL (Hekaton) for queue messaging system?

Tags: sql-server, queue, message-queue, optimistic-concurrency, memory-optimized-tables

I work with a platform that have a messaging system that uses SQL server tables as queues.

That system was based on this:  [Using Tables as queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

ATM we are facing some scalability issues, since this distributive schema is mainly based on SQL Locks and disk operations in order to guarantee the durability/coherence of data.

In order to solve the disk based I/O bottleneck and to improve the bad distributive logic, we are thinking in changing disk based SQL tables to In memory SQL (Hekaton) available at SQL 2014 & 2016.

I've read some stuff about Hekaton already, but I'm still not sure if this is the best approach, or if is possible to implement those queues into In memory and if this is the best approach.

Most of those queues are implementing **pessimistic concurrency**, and Hekaton uses no locks system only **optimistic concurrency** (based on multi-versioning). Is it "always" (I know this is a bad word) possible to change the pessimistic concurrency into an optimistic one? For example on the above queues.

Is Hekaton made for many inserts/deletes (enqueue/dequeue), order rows (FIFO queues), and a lot of variations of table sizes (workload variations on the server will increase/decrease the queues size)? It will be possible to update properly the Statistics for the query performance of native store procedures?

I feel like native compiled SQL store procedures will improve a lot the performance, but I'm not sure if this kind of implementation (correlated FIFO queues) are good to be used on Hekaton, since I'm not finding any examples of "In memory queues" implementations using Hekaton.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement in Hekaton what you described - as you mentioned, the app will have to take care of retrying in case of the transaction being aborted due to concurrency on *the same row*. Having said that, you also have to consider that SQL 2014 does not support large binary objects, you will need to use SQL 2016 or workaround it as we do it for ASP.NET Session state:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kenkilty/archive/2014/07/03/asp-net-session-state-using-sql-sever-in-memory.aspx

Hekaton is designed for OLTP, that means, lots of inserts, updates, deletes.

Plan ahead the memory requirements:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx

Comment: I've already implemented 3 types of queues using Hekaton. Made a workaround to support more than 8060b limitation: when the payload of a message is higher than the limit I only store a reference to a table in disk. I think this will work since I won't have many messages higher than the limit, but 2016 will release a version with much higher limit. I've implemented also a retry logic when a concurrency happens. I'm not sure yet if I have much gains from this implementation since the project is in standby, but I feel that Hekaton has A LOT of limitations that need a lot of workarounds.

Comment: We closed the gap for 2016 a lot, including the T-SQL surface area. I think your effort will be worthy, we are heavily investing in Hekaton. I forgot to mention that you should stick to natively compiled procedures as much as possible. Also, the ASP.NET session state mentioned above comes with source code, so take a look and compare notes with your implementation.